# How to verify final method with PowerMockito

Tags: mockito, powermock

There are verifyStatic and verifyPrive methods in PowerMockito but no verifyFinal. Is it possible to verify final method invocations with PowerMockito?

Best regards, Eugene.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, it appears that it's enough to add class being verified into PrepareForTest and then use normal Mockito.verify.